# Xamarin.Android No style resource found

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin for an android app on MacOS, my question is very simple but I haven't found anything online and I'm getting mad at this: I just want to set the app style to be Fullscreen and without a title bar so I changed my `Manifest.xml` as follows:

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" />
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoTitleBar.FullScreen"></application>`

And when it tries to compile it gives me the following error: `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.Material.NoTitleBar.FullScreen')(APT0000)`

I tried every other fullscreen theme and no title bar that Xamarin suggests in the drop down menu in the designer but it gives me always that resource error

Comment: What is your `minSdkVersion`? And on which Android version you are testing the app?

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to set the app style to be Fullscreen and without a title bar

You can add this in your `AppTheme`:

```
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

And your application doesn't need to change, just refer to it:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" 
               android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
               android:label="@string/app_name" 
               android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" 
               android:supportsRtl="true" 
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
 </application>
```

I can't find `style/Theme.Material.NoTitleBar.FullScreen` in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values).